# Connect to remote PostgreSQL database using hostname instead of ip address

Tags: vb.net, networking, dns, connection-string, npgsql

when constructing my connection string in my vb.net program, I can connect to a PostgreSQL database on another computer if I use an ip address of that server. However, is there a way to use the hostname of the server instead of the ip address?

I am using npgsql in vb.net, and my connection string is:

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Can I do something like:

```
Server=server-name;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

PostgreSQL documentation says I can use the address/name of the server but that doesn't seem to connect (No such host is known).

**EDIT:**

Here is the link for the documentation I found. It is npgsql's documentation though, not postgreSQL like I thought.
http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html

it says this under the Connection String parameters section: Server - Address/Name of PostgreSQL Server

Comment: You are quoting the documentation, but I don't see a link?

Comment: are you sure the DNS resolution for this host works in the vb environment running this code?

Comment: @regilero I am not quite sure what you are asking.. Everything works fine using the IP address to connect to the server now, but I don't want the end user to have to be constantly be changing the IP address of the server on the client machine, nor do I want them to have to figure out how to set up a static IP address if I can avoid it.

Comment: ok, and do you know if this server-name exists? does it match an IP in a hosts file or a DNS server? If you do not know what DNS is google that thing first.

Comment: well, I guess that would be my other question, is the postgresql server name the same as the hostname? I do know the hostname exists. Are you saying the hostname needs to be added to the pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: The sever name is a DNS name, that can be set in /etc/hosts. The hostname in /etc/hostname is just a local thing, unrelated to DNS and unrelated to PostgreSQL. And the pg_hba.conf does not need to know anything about the server name, the pg_hba.conf will need to allow the client IP and network. When you use a name in a connection string you -- the program, here vb -- make a DNS resolution to translate it into an IP.

Comment: Ohh ok, so what you are saying is I need to actually convert a hostname into an IP address withing my program. I used SQL Server express a little before postgreSQL and with SQL Server you could connect with hostname/serverinstance so I was hoping postgreSQL would be that easy. I guess now I just need to figure out the code to return the ip address of a hostname.